# How to build a regex to analyze all links on a web page?

Tags: php, regex

I am building a web crawler in PHP, meant for Intranet use (we're dealing with a huge Intranet). I managed to download a web page using the cURL functions, but now I want to scan the content for links. I am trying to find all obvious links and split them in their corresponding scheme/authority/path/query/fragment so I can index them properly.

Is there a known regular expression that matches all the links, including the ones like `<img src="../images/header/logo.png" />`, `background-image: url(..)` and `<a href="?query#lonely-fragment">`.

What are all the plain-text link representations that I can find using regular expressions in PHP?

Comment: Do not parse HTML with regexps. Use a XML Parser, such as DOMDocument.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be better off parsing documents using a proper HTML parser.  Regex is not really suited for this kind of thing.

Once you have done that, it's fairly trivial using XPath to scan for e.g. `//img/@src` or `//a/@href` to find all of the content links in the document itself.

If you want to scan CSS, you will also need to look for `//style[@type='text/css']` and `//link[@rel='stylesheet'][@type='text/css']/@href` and then use a proper CSS parser to extract all of the content.  (Or, if you want to be lazy, you could *probably* get away with the regex `/url\((.*?)\)/`.)